# A moving star at 6pm (Indonesia Time)

Tags: star, identify-this-object

After I back from Minimart, it's about 6pm though, I saw the sky, yeah a beauty evening sky, but I sense a something weird from the sky, It look like a star at first it moving in low speed, I Though that was a Kite or plane, but it cant be plane cuz it moved up then turned right then turned left and get back.
it size and it light same as a normal Stars.
It's move like as Kite, but it so bright like star.
after a few minutes, it's stoped move, but then its Moved Fastest Like A shooting stars, and yes it has a tail like Comet,that moved in Light speed.

after that I got back to home,
I asked to my friend on FB,
I said that I saw a moving star,
I didnt say it when,
but my friend asked me back,
"was that do along 6pm?"
"whoa, how can be You know that?"
and then my friend said if that was an UFO
he ever saw that many times.

(sorry for bad English)

Comment: Could it be a quad-copter with an LED flying fairly high, or even a radio-control plane? Does your FB friend happen to own one? Also, take a look at the link in the comment above this. There are several good possible explanations there to consider.